# What is the Structure of recorded data in j2me using audio/basic as type?

Tags: java, java-me, arrays, mmapi, sample-rate

I am recording audio from microphone in a j2me phone to a ByteArrayOutputStream as follows

```
  p = Manager.createPlayer("capture://audio?encoding=pcm");
  p.realize();  
  RecordControl rc = (RecordControl)p.getControl("RecordControl");
  ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  rc.setRecordStream(output);  
  rc.startRecord();
  p.start();
```

what is the structure of recorded data ?

I mean where are the info like sample rate, size per sample,no of channels etc. stored

can i get those info after finishing the recording by converting the ByteArrayOutputStream to ByteArray using Output.toByteArray() ?

I want to get those info directly from the recorded data before loading it into another player to play it

Comment: it will be in byte array kind of structure

Comment: o.O see this ..https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

I'm asking something like this

Comment: oh ok, well no idea about such format.